# Android: How to get event and calendar id from Observer/Receiver for CalendarContract.EVENT removal

Tags: android, events, broadcastreceiver, android-calendar, contentobserver

I am currently working on an app that adds calendar events to a calendar of the user's choosing. The user can either use my app or the another Calendar app to edit the event. I am now trying to write a receiver or observer that works in the background and listens for changes to the event or instance. I basically want my app to know when an event or instance of an event is being deleted so I can clean up some data in my app's database, especially when the event or instance is being deleted from ANOTHER CALENDAR APP. I was thinking I could register an observer in the manifest file using an intent filter. I found the following example using a Broadcast Receiver, and it seems to work for the most part however I would like to know how to get the calendarId, eventId and maybe even the instanceId of the event being removed. Any ideas?

```
<receiver android:name=".calendar.CalendarChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
      <data android:scheme="content"/>
      <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately with content observers you don't get any details about what has changed.
The only info you get is the changed content Uri (when available), and this is only from API 16:
[onChange(boolean, android.net.Uri)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html#onChange%28boolean,%20android.net.Uri%29)